# How to get the actual svg fill attribute using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I'm able to change fill attribute of an SVG rectangle with jQuery when I click on it.

But how can I get the **actual** fill attribute of this rectangle?

Here is my try:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var svg = $('#test_svg').find('#rect10')[0];
    $("#test_button").click(function(){
        console.log(svg.getAttribute('style'));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test_svg" class="MusiopolisImages scaling-svg-container">
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <svg
        id="svg8"
        version="1.1"
       
        class="scaling-svg" 
        viewBox="0 0 300 320" 
        height="200" 
        width="200">
        <g
            id="layer1"
            inkscape:groupmode="layer"
            inkscape:label="Calque 1">
            <rect
                y="100.54166"
                x="26.458334"
                height="69.547623"
                width="77.863091"
                id="rect10"
                style="fill:#ffffff;stroke-width:2;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none"
            />
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
<button id="test_button">Show rect10 fill attribute</button>
```

Edit: With this try I get the whole actual style of element `#rect10` (`"fill:#ffffff;stroke-width:2;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none"`).

**I'm so close! How can I get the fill attribute only?**

Comment: Your svg has the id of `svg8` but you're selecting `#test_svg`. Where is the `#test_svg` element?

Comment: #test_svg is the id of the <div> surrounding the svg.  By replacing .find(#rect10) by .find('svg') I'm able to get any attribute of the svg. But I want to get the attribute fill of #rect10 which is inside the svg. How can I? Thanks for your help.

Comment: See @David's answer below.  All you need is `let rect = document.querySelector('#rect10');
console.log(rect.style.fill);`

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `style` attribute of the DOM Element:

example: `alert(svg.style.fill)`

Comment: Thank you so much! This is what I was missing.